# File Reading in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, filereader

I want to access url of file which user select through pop up file directory navigation window. My browse button tag is:

```
<input  type="file" id="loadFile"/>
```

On the back end, i can access the file url in javascript, but not sure how to do it in PHP.

Comment: JavaScript = frontend.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the correct enctype for the form.

Otherwise, you utilize the [$_FILES](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) super global.

This is covered extensively in the [PHP Manual regarding uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

The original filename is available in `$_FILES['load file']['name']`

Since it seems that you actually want a way to have the user provide a url to a file, the way to handle that is to simply implement a text input and accept the url there, and process the url on the server, using an HTTP client that fetches and stores the file on the user's behalf.

For years people have been using the curl extension, which is fast and highly functional.  There are also a number of client libraries written in php like [Guzzle.](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Yea, i went through it before posting the question but not quite understanding how to code it..

Comment: If you have a specific question about something that isn't clear, update the original question.  The main thing to understand is that you need to use move_uploaded_file() to take the newly uploaded file and move it to a permanent place on your server.

Comment: Is there any way to pass url string from javaScript to php?

Comment: Sure but then you are not utilizing a file upload.  File uploads only handle local files on a user's machine.  To handle a url, you would need to instead use some sort of fetching mechanism.  Typically what people use is an HTTP client library like Guzzle or the old standby of curl.